# What is an example of a continuous but not closed function?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I have two questions about closed functions.

Firstly, we say that a function is closed if it maps closed subsets in the domain to closed subsets in the co-domain. Polynomials are typical examples of closed functions.

However, I'm having trouble thinking of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ but is not a closed function.

My second question is that if given a function $f$, what steps would one take to actually **prove** that it is closed? A sketch would be an easy way to demonstrate it, but I am not entirely sure how you would actually prove it.

Comment: $\arctan$ should do it.

Comment: No, a closed interval in the domain of $\arctan $ gives a closed interval

Comment: @Vincent $\mathbb{R}$ is closed. $\arctan(\mathbb{R}) = (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ is not (in $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Yes, indeed, sorry

Comment: @Vincent You are fogetting that the whole $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$. If $f=\exp$ or $f=\arctan$, then $f(\mathbb{R})$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$. It seems that when you are saying "closed' you are adding "bounded" under your breath; but every bounded closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact, and it is mapped by any continuous function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$  to a compact hence closed subset or $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I admit that I am guilty of having forgotten that $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $e^x$ also works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^2+1}$. Its image is $(0,1]$, which is neither open nor closed.